# gcc cross compilation for powerpc7448

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, embedded-linux, powerpc

I want to cross compile the gcc for powerpc7448, and after this I want to run one simple program and get the elf from the  cross compiled gcc for powerpc7448,I am using the linux OS,could anyone please suggest me the steps, cross compilation gcc for powerpc7448(any link) and what are all the components are required for cross compilation,Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a toolchain to have a cross compiler (in case you are not compiling on the target machine). Simplest way is to check Buildroot distribuition.

Answer (score 0):

Try ELDK cross compiler toolchain (linux distributions) for PowerPC:

ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/eldk/4.2/ppc-linux-x86/distribution/README.html

Check Eldk version 4.2.

Help: https://www.denx.de/wiki/ELDK-5/WebHome

> **ppc_74xx-gcc** from eldk can be used to compile for your platform.
>
> `
>   $ ppc_74xx-gcc -c myfile.c

`

Comment: Thank you for the replay,I have installed the "core-image-base-generic-powerpc.tar.gz" and "eldk-5.6-powerpc.iso"

Comment: After this how do I proceed for cross compilatiion

Comment: you can find "ppc_74xx-gcc" bin file in that tool chain.

Comment: after extracting the "core-image-base-generic-powerpc.tar.gz" zip file ,I am getting the usr,home,var,sbin like that directories,where I can get the "ppc_74xx-gcc" bin file...could you help me

Comment: from the root directory, just give : find -iname "ppc_74xx*"

Comment: It should be in bin or sbin. If you not find this file, make sure you have downloaded the correct eldk version.

Comment: I am not founding, I downloaded the "eldk-5.6-poweerpc.iso" and I extracted it,after extracting I got differrent tar.gz files,after this I extracted the "core-image...tar.gz" file after this I am getting the usr,lib,bin,sbin directories ,I am not founding that ppc_74xx bin in any directories..I attached the screenshot  with my question please go through that one,And please let me know what mistake I am doing..

Comment: After downloading and extracting the .iso file how to proceed next...any link for this..please let me know...

Comment: https://ftp.denx.de/pub/eldk/4.2/ppc-linux-x86/iso/ppc-2008-04-01.iso download this file. mount this iso to some folder and do install from the soure. Instructions given in this link https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/ELDKUsage. you can find ppc_74xx-gcc in install directory of usr/bin